# How to set the hover state equals the active state with li clearfix element using ui-sref-active="active"

Tags: html, css, angularjs, url-routing

I create 2 buttons on one line and have some problem with styling them correctly with the template i'm using.

The button has 4 states but when client is active it goes wrong.

The first state is when nothing is happens.

[image]

The second state is when the + sign is active or in hover status

[image]

On de third state when i hover over clients i get this:
which works correctly.

[image]

But when the client is active i get the same result as when nothing is active.
So what could i do to get the active state equals to the hover state from picture 3.

[image]

the html goes like this:

```
    <li  ui-sref-active="active" class="clearfix li-button"> <a class="btn btn-primary-li-left" ui-sref="app.clients"  ripple=""><em class="sidebar-item-icon icon-head"></em> Clients  </a> <a  class="btn btn-primary-li-right "  ui-sref="app.addclient" >+</a>  </li>
```

I use app.html as template where i have this:

```
<aside ng-include="'html/main/templates/sidebar.html'" ng-class="app.theme.sidebar"></aside>
```

the class app.theme.sidebar == #bg-white

The css i added is this it works without the template :

```
.li-button  a{
    float:left;
    display: block;
}

.li-button  a:first-child{
    width: 77%;
}

.li-button  a:last-child{
    width: 15%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    color: #ffffff;

}

.btn-primary-li-left {
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;

    font-weight: 900;
    height: 40px;
}

.btn-primary-li-right {
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;

    font-weight: 900;
}


.li-button  a:last-child:hover {

    color: #ffffff;
    background: #0493ac;
}

.li-button  a:first-child:hover +a:last-child{
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #0e8eac;
}
```

I think it has something todo with this which is from the template :

```
#bg-white .nav > li.active,
.bg-white .nav > li.active {
    background-color: #0df9ee !important;
}

#bg-white .nav > li:hover > a,
.bg-white .nav > li:hover > a {
    background-color: #00f3bd;
}
#bg-white .nav > li.active > a,
.bg-white .nav > li.active > a {
    background-color: #f32400;
}
```

**EDIT**

So i did a bit modification on the answer of Shane but i still do not get the result i wanted it got even weirder.

if i do this the button is green

```
#bg-white .nav > li > a.btn-primary-li-left,
.bg-white .nav > li >a.btn-primary-li-left{
    background-color: #05f900 !important;
}
```

but when i add the active element nothing happens and get the same result as the first picture in this question.

```
#bg-white .nav > li > a.btn-primary-li-left.active,
.bg-white .nav > li >a.btn-primary-li-left.active {
    background-color: #05f900 !important;
}
```

Comment: To set default color as white, add the property to the `a:last-child` selector that you already have. For the third one, I can't see the problem happening. It changes a different color (not grey) based on the `..:hover + a:last-child` selector.

Comment: Then your problem could be elsewhere in the code (something possibly overriding). Can you create a demo?

Comment: Loading last might not always help. There might be more specific selectors elsewhere (either within your own code or within bootstrap's code).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not targeting the same selector structure, remove the `#bg-white ...` CSS for `.active` and try this:

```
.li-button.active a:first-child + a:last-child {
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #0e8eac;
}

.li-button.active a {
    background: #eee;
}
```

Working example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PPdOvZ?editors=110

**EDIT**

Based on your edit, the active class isn't being applied to the anchor tag. It's being applied to the `li`, change your updated code to this:

```
#bg-white .nav > li.active > a.btn-primary-li-left,
.bg-white .nav > li.active > a.btn-primary-li-left {
    background-color: #05f900 !important;
}
```

Comment: For some reason this still does not work. Notice when i remove the last <a> element it does work. So it is a step in the right direction.. Do you have any idea why this could happen ?

Comment: @user3475722 You're applying the styles to `.li-button` and `.btn-primary...` so you would need to overwrite those when `.active` is applied by targeting the same selectors.

Comment: Damm i did not know css could be this tricky. I try to overwrite the selectors but no result. Then i changed the the class names to li-button-li-left and right. To see if this would work. But for some reason when i have 2 li elements the first one does not want to be activated.

Comment: @user3475722 If you created a plunkr, codepen or a fiddle showing the issue in action then I would be able to help you better but I've done all I can really do for now.

Comment: Ok i created a small project with all the same css styles but there it works. I'm going to search for the issue but i don't understand why this works, if i find the issue i will create a fiddle about it.

Comment: I will accept your answer since it the solution for the question i asked, But i did not found a solution for my problem but i think it out of the scope of the question i asked.